# Run crawling function sequentially on multiple URLs with Scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, twisted

How can I run a crawler on multiple URLs sequentially? we already know that we can pass multiple URLs & allowed_domains at the same time but I need a function to handle this as follows:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    start_urls = []
    allowed_domains = []

    def parse(self, response):
        # extract the data you want from the response
        data = {
            "url": response.url,
            "title": response.xpath("//title/text()").get(),
            # add more fields as needed
        }
        yield data

def do_crawl(start_url, allowed_domain):
    # create a spider instance with the given parameters
    spider = MySpider
    spider.start_urls = [start_url]
    spider.allowed_domains = [allowed_domain]

    # create a crawler process and configure the settings
    process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
        "FEEDS": {
            "results.json": {"format": "json"}, # save the results in a json file
        },
        # add more settings as needed
    })

    # start the crawling process
    process.crawl(spider)
    process.start()

# run the do_crawl function on multiple urls
do_crawl("https://www.wikipedia.org/", "wikipedia.org")
do_crawl("https://www.stackoverflow.com/", "stackoverflow.com")
```

As you can see, I need to run `do_crawl` on two URLs (not necessarily at the same time). The above code gives me the following error:

```
2023-05-31 12:51:43 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\", line 38, in <module>
    do_crawl("https://www.bing.com/", "bing.com")
  File "C:\Users\", line 34, in do_crawl
    process.start()
  File "C:\Users\crawler.py", line 383, in start
    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)  # blocking call
  File "C:\Users\internet\base.py", line 1317, in run
    self.startRunning(installSignalHandlers=installSignalHandlers)
  File "C:\Users\base.py", line 1299, in startRunning
    ReactorBase.startRunning(cast(ReactorBase, self))
  File "C:\Users\", line 843, in startRunning
    raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable
```

Comment: If you want to run Scrapy in Jupyter, then look at something like [crochet](https://pypi.org/project/crochet/) or better, don't use Scrapy in Jupyter or Colab.

Comment: @Amir it's in the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process).